# Beginning with Ruby on Rails. How do Gemfile and how gems work when specifying versions to download?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, version

I tried reading the documentation but this still wasn't clear to me:

Suppose my I have the following statements in my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'

...
```

I'm trying to learn how to use Ruby on Rails this website: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and it says that I need to have the `sqlite3` gem for this version of rails (3.2.2).

My question is: if I don't specify the exact version of the `sqlite3` gem for the system to download when I run `bundle install` then will it install the latest version that works with the version of rails and ruby that I'm working with (suppose it's 3.2.2 and 1.8.7 p-352 respectively) or will it just download the latest version of the sqlite3 gem available whether it works with what I have installed or not?

I'm not really sure how this aspect of the Gemfile works and the documentation hasn't been clear or I haven't found where it explicitly says this or otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it will install the latest version of sqlite3 that is compatible with the dependencies specified by the other gems you've listed.

Say, rails said it only worked with sqlite3 that was greater than 1.0 but less than 4.0, it might install 3.9.5.  I'm making all these numbers up, just an example.

In fact, I don't know if rails *does* specify any particular versions of sqlite3 it requires. Presumably 'json' doesn't either, since it's got nothing to do with databases. If none of the other gems you list specify any requirements for sqlite3, it'll just install the latest version available.

'bundle install' is using [bundler](http://gembundler.com/), some more about how it resolves dependencies is [here](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html).

So bundler will download the latest gem that meets the requirements of all the other gems you list. Say you listed a gem A which required sqlite3 earlier than 2.0 and a gem B that required sqlite3 later than 2.1 -- 'bundle install' would complain and say it can't satisfy them all.

This relies on the gems own advertisements of each of their own requirements for the other gems they rely on though. Sometimes they can be wrong, or missing. It may be that rails doesn't actually specify what version of sqlite3 it requires -- since it doesn't actually *require* sqlite3 at all (you don't have to use sqlite with rails), this may very well be. In which case bundler can't do much but get the latest version of sqlite3. Which doesn't guarantee that version will work. But it can only do so much.

You also mention the issue of compatibility with specific versions of ruby, like 1.8.7-p352.  Bundler is less capable there, you can't generally count on it knowing what version is compatible with a particular version of ruby (because there's not a great way for gems to express this in a way that bundler can use, alas).

But in *general*, things work out. If you don't know or care what version of sqlite3 (or any other gem) you want, but know you want one -- do what you did, run 'bundle install', see if it works. It probably will. If it doesn't, google the error message and you'll probably find someone explaining why it didn't and what you need to do instead.

PS: If that wasn't enough. sqlite3 is sort of an odd case, because while Rails is designed to work with it, it's not *required*.  But Rails by default, when creating a new app with latest version of rails `rails new my_app`, will *already* put sqlite3 in your Gemfile for you. And it'll do it just like you did, without a version constraint. That's reason to feel pretty confident it will work fine. Note that in rails 3.2.2, `rails new my_app` will put some other things in your Gemfile that *do* have more specific versions listed, like `gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'`, because while those things aren't absolutely required for Rails (or else they'd be expressed as requirements and not need to be explicitly in your app's Gemfile), the rails installer knows that only certain versions will work.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly new to Rails as well so correct me if I am wrong.

The Gemfile looks to the gems directory for the gems listed and has no impact on actually "installing" them. Performing a "gem install" command without a version will grab the most recent version listed no matter what your Gemfile says. When you "bundle install", that is when version-specific lookups happen in your gems directory.

Answer (score 1):

Bundler always looks at your `Gemfile.lock` file first when you're doing `bundle install`. If you open that file, you'll see the gems as well as the version used by your application. This is convenient for existing projects because you're always sure that every other developer involved with the project will be working with the same gem versions.

If it doesn't find that file (i.e. doing `rails new projectname`), or the specified gem or version in `Gemfile` isn't consistent with `Gemfile.lock`, it will download the latest or specified version of the gem.